# AxiosError: req failed with status 404

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, axios

[this is my sign up component in which I have created (handlesubmit) function so whenever I click on submit button this function will fire which will save my data to Mongodb atlas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5aLp.png)  
I have created login/signup page and on submitting data has to store in database atlas but getting Axios error that .

```
AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code
: 
"ERR_BAD_REQUEST"
config
: 
{transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}
message
: 
"Request failed with status code 404"
name
: 
"AxiosError"
request
: 
XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
response
: 
{data: '<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n<head>\n<meta char…<pre>Cannot POST /api/user</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n', status: 404, statusText: 'Not Found', headers: AxiosHeaders, config: {…}, …}
stack
: 
"AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404\n    at settle (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:69046:12)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:67746:66)"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Error
```

Comment: The image you share it looks good show the HTML form code and also the controller and route of backend. If it's possible share or show the entire frontend signin js file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76935912/error404-axios-cannot-post-api-user     
      check here