# ERROR404: AXIOS: Cannot POST '/api/user'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

## On submitting form data im getting Axios error as bad req on consoling the error it shows cannot get POST '/api/user'

this is my sign up page. so when i am submitting the form and sending data to databse atlas it is showing error that cannot post 'api/user'

```
import { FormControl, FormLabel, Input, InputGroup, InputRightElement, VStack, Button, } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useToast } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

const Sign = () => {
    const [Name, setName] = useState();
    const [Email, setEmail] = useState();
    const [show, setShow] = useState();
    const [password, setPassword] = useState();
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [pic, setPic] = useState();
    const [confirmpassword, setConfirmpassword] = useState();
    const toast = useToast();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const submitHandler = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        if (!Name || !Email || !password || !confirmpassword) {
            toast({
                title: 'Please Fill all the Fields',
                status: 'warning',
                duration: 5000,
                isClosable: true,
                position: 'bottom'
            });
            setLoading(false);
            return;
        }

        if (password !== confirmpassword) {
            toast({
                title: 'Please Fill all the Fields',
                status: 'warning',
                duration: 5000,
                isClosable: true,
                position: 'bottom'
            });
            setLoading(false);
            return;
        }

        try {
            const config = {
                headers: {
                    "Content-type": "application/json",
                }
            };

            const { data } = await axios.post("/api/user",
                { Name, Email, password, pic },
                config
            ).then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
            });
            toast({
                title: 'Registration Successful',
                status: 'success',
                duration: 5000,
                isClosable: true,
                position: 'bottom'
            });

            localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(data));
            console.log(data);
            setLoading(false);
            navigate('/chats')
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.response.data);
            // toast({
            //     title: 'Error Occured',
            //     description: error.response.data.message,
            //     status: 'error',
            //     duration: 5000,
            //     isClosable: true,
            //     position: 'bottom'
            // });
            setLoading(false);
        }
    }

    const handleClick = () => setShow(!show);
    const postDetails = (pics) => {
        setLoading(true);
        if (pics === undefined) {
            toast({
                title: 'Please select an Image',
                status: 'warning',
                duration: 5000,
                isClosable: true,
                position: 'bottom'
            });
            return;
        }

        if (pics.type === "image/jpeg" || pics.type === "image/png") {
            const data = new FormData();
            data.append("file", pics);
            data.append("upload_preset", "chatApplication");
            data.append("cloud_name", "dpiud4zo4");
            fetch("https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/dpiud4zo4/image/upload", {
                method: 'post',
                body: data,
            }).then((res) => res.json()).then(data => {
                setPic(data.url.toString());
                console.log(data.url.toString());
                setLoading(false);
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
                setLoading(false);
            })
        }
        else {
            toast({
                title: 'Please select an Image',
                status: 'warning',
                duration: 5000,
                isClosable: true,
                position: 'bottom'
            });
            setLoading(false);
            return;
        }
    };

    return (
        <VStack spacing='5px'>
            <FormControl id='FirstName' isRequired>
                <FormLabel>Name</FormLabel>
                <Input placeholder='Enter your Name' onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl id='Email' isRequired>
                <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
                <Input placeholder='Enter your Email' onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl id='password' isRequired>
                <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
                <InputGroup size='md'>
                    <Input
                        pr='4.5rem'
                        type={show ? 'text' : 'password'}
                        placeholder='Enter password'
                        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <InputRightElement width='4.5rem'>
                        <Button h='1.75rem' size='sm' onClick={handleClick}>
                            {show ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}
                        </Button>
                    </InputRightElement>
                </InputGroup>
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl id='cpassword' isRequired>
                <FormLabel>Confirm Password</FormLabel>
                <InputGroup size='md'>
                    <Input
                        pr='4.5rem'
                        type={show ? 'text' : 'password'}
                        placeholder='Confiem password'
                        onChange={(e) => setConfirmpassword(e.target.value)}
                    />
                    <InputRightElement width='4.5rem'>
                        <Button h='1.75rem' size='sm' onClick={handleClick}>
                            {show ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}
                        </Button>
                    </InputRightElement>
                </InputGroup>
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl id='pic' isRequired>
                <FormLabel>Upload your picture</FormLabel>
                <Input type='file' padding='2px' accept='image/*' onChange={(e) => postDetails(e.target.files[0])} />
            </FormControl>
            <Button
                width='100%'
                onClick={submitHandler}
                colorScheme='cyan'
                marginTop='15px'
                isLoading={loading}
            >
                Submit
            </Button>

        </VStack>
    )
}

export default Sign
```

## My server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

require("./config/db");
const userRoutes = require("./routes/userRoutes");

dotenv.config();

app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("hello")
})

app.use('/api/user', userRoutes)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`server is listening at ${port}`);
})
```

## My userRoutes page

```
const express = require('express');
const { registerUser, authUser } = require('../controllers/userController');

const router = express.Router();

router.route("/").post(registerUser);

router.post("/login", authUser);

module.exports = router;
```

## My userControl.js

```
const User = require("../models/user");
const generateToken = require("../config/generateToken");


const registerUser = async (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, password, pic } = req.body;

    if (!name || !email || !password) {
        throw new Error("Please Enter all the fields");
    }

    const userExists = await User.findOne({ email });
    try {


        if (userExists) {
            res.status(400);
            throw new Error("User already exists");
        }

        const user = await User.create({
            name,
            email,
            password,
            pic,
        });

        if (user) {
            res.status(201).json({
                _id: user._id,
                name: user.name,
                email: user.email,
                pic: user.pic,
                token: generateToken(user._id),
            })
            console.log(user);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        // else {
        res.status(400);
        console.log(err);
        throw new Error("Failed to create the User");
        // }

    }
};

const authUser = async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    const user = await User.findOne({ email });

    if (user && (await user.matchPassword(password))) {
        res.json({
            _id: user._id,
            name: user.name,
            email: user.email,
            pic: user.pic,
            token: generateToken(user._id),
        });
    }
}

module.exports = { registerUser, authUser };
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this part and then try I think I got your problem

Change the state names to small letters

```
const [name, setName] = useState();
const [email, setEmail] = useState();
```

And and also in `submitHandler`

```
const { data } = await axios.post("/api/user",
                { name, email, password, pic },
                config
            ).then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
            });
```

This problem is because of a typo you made you should follow the camelCase rule that is not necessary but make sure when you are sending the value from frontend to the backend where you receive the value `req.body` make sure the variable names you use in your model matches with your controller and also matches the variable name you are sending from frontend